# Can Python object instances have different logger levels at the same time?

Tags: python, oop, logging

I wanted different objects in my program to have different logging levels. Is that possible?

I made a base class as shown below containing methods to set the logging levels.

```
class Logging():
""" Utility class for common methods."""

logging_levels = ['DEBUG','INFO']#,'WARNING','ERROR'

@property
def verbosity(self):
    return self.__verbosity

@verbosity.setter
def verbosity(self,verbosity):
    """Method to set verbosity of logging on terminal. Different classes may have different levels of verbosity."""

    assert verbosity in self.logging_levels, '{} is not a valid logging level!'.format(verbosity)

    self.__verbosity = verbosity

    #Set logging level - {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR}
    if verbosity == 'DEBUG':
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    elif verbosity == 'INFO':
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    elif verbosity == 'WARNING':
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    print('{}:Logging level is set to:{}'.format(self.name,verbosity))

    return self.__verbosity
```

My other two classes inherit from the 'Logging' class and I have following in their respective *init* methods:

```
self.verbosity = verbosity
```

However, what I observed is that whenever an instance of either class is used to set the logging level, the logging level is set globally.
Is there any way to restrict logging levels to specific class instances?

Edited:
Using the suggestion from John Gordon, I was able to come up with a solution. Please see below.

Answer (score 1):

```
if verbosity == 'DEBUG':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

elif verbosity == 'INFO':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

elif verbosity == 'WARNING':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Calling `getLogger()` without a name returns the root logger.

So, all of these calls operate on the root logger, erasing any previous setting.

One way around this is to supply a name when calling `getLogger()`, and ensure the name is different for each class instance.

Comment: I can't help without seeing your updated code.  Also, please include the code that actually performs the logging.

Comment: I was able to resolve it. It seems I needed to initialize loggers when the instance was created, and use that logger. I have provided the answer below. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by making the following changes to my Logger class.

```
class Logging():
""" Utility class for common methods."""

logging_levels = ['DEBUG','INFO']#,'WARNING','ERROR'


def initialize_logger(self):
    """Initialize loggers for different classes."""

    self.logger = logging.getLogger(type(self).__name__)

@property
def verbosity(self):
    return self.__verbosity

@verbosity.setter
def verbosity(self,verbosity):
    """Method to set verbosity of logging on terminal. Different classes may have different levels of verbosity."""

    assert verbosity in self.logging_levels, '{} is not a valid logging level!'.format(verbosity)

    self.__verbosity = verbosity

    #Set logging level - {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR}
    if verbosity == 'DEBUG':
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    elif verbosity == 'INFO':
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    elif verbosity == 'WARNING':
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

    self.logger.debug('{}:Logging level is set to:{}'.format(self.name,verbosity))

    return self.__verbosity
```

I added the initialize_logger() method and called it in the **init** function of the classes I wanted to log from.

```
self.initialize_logger()
#Set logging level - {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR}
self.verbosity = verbosity
```

Then finally, I used the `logger` object I created with `initialize_logger()` instead of `logging.debug()`.

```
self.logger.debug('My log message')
```

Now I can control the logging level separately for all the classes.